# Host journal logs no present in EFK Kubernetes stack

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd, efk

I'm using [kube-fluentd-operator](https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator) to aggregate logs using `fluentd` into `Elasticsearch` and query them in `Kibana`.

I can see my application (pods) logs inside the cluster.
However I cannot see the journal logs (systemd units, kubelet, etc) from the hosts inside the cluster.

There are no noticeable messages in fluentd's pods logs and the stack works for logs coming from applications.
Inside the `fluentd` container I have access to the `/var/log/journal` directory (`drwxr-sr-x  3 root  101      4096 May 21 12:37 journal`).
Where should I look next to get the journald logs in my EFK stack?

Here's the `kube-system.conf` file attached to the `kube-system` namespace:

```
<match systemd.** kube.kube-system.** k8s.** docker>
  # all k8s-internal and OS-level logs

  @type elasticsearch
  host "logs-es-http.logs"
  port "9200"
  scheme "https"
  ssl_verify false
  user "u1"
  password "password"
  logstash_format true
  #with_transporter_log true
  #@log_level debug
  validate_client_version true
  ssl_version TLSv1_2
</match>
```

Minimal, simple, according to the docs.

Is it possible that my search terms are wrong?
What should I search for in order to get the journal logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having tried every possible solution (from enabling `log_level debug`, to only having the  `kube-system` namespace monitored, to adding `runAsGroup: 101` to the containers) all I was left with was changing what I was using for log aggregation and decided to switch from that operator to the `DaemonSet` provided by `fluent` themselves: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset

This switch has proved successful and the search of the `systemd` units works from inside the EFK stack.